# Can a pandas column be quickly converted to datetime if the column values contain letters?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas column with ~100k rows that contains date strings. I'm attempting to convert the strings to datetime objects, but the strings currently contain a letter. Here's an example:

'2020-11-10T02:00:12.000'

Currently, I'm updating the column ('created_date') row by row to remove the letter, like so:

```
for date in df.created_date:
    df.created_date.loc[date] = date[0:10] + ' ' + date[11:]
```

This would allow me to convert the column values to datetime objects with the following code:

```
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(
                          df['created_date'], 
                          format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
)
```

However, that first block of code is taking long to run because there are so many rows. Is there a way to use pd.to_datetime, without that preprocessing step, to accomplish this task more quickly?

Comment: You missed the T between date and time.

Comment: the format is pretty standard [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601); just use `df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date']) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the letter into the `format`:

```
# notice the `T` after `%d` 
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'], 
                                    format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all mapping over a column is way faster than iterating through each element, so that will help

but also you can use datetime or something like dateparser to convert the string to a datetime object without removing the letter

so this should make your life easier

```
import dateparser
df['created_date'] = df['created_date'].map(lambda d: dateparser.parse(d))
```

Comment: you also do not need a mapping. just `pd.to_datetime`, which will also auto-infer the format correctly.

Comment: *mapping over a column is way faster than iterating through each element*, this doesn't sound right in the case of mapping with a function.